# Yii customized CGridView undefined constant

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I am new to Yii, I have the follwing code, `'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'email',
        array(
            'name' => 'deleted',
            'value' => $model->deleted == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No',
        ),`
I want to display YES if the deleted field from the database equal 1 or NO if not. 
and it keeps giving me a PHP notice :  Use of undefined constant Yes. 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
My hole wedgit

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'users-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'email',
    array(
        'name' => 'deleted',


    ),
    /*
    'pass',
    'salt',

    'first',
    'last',
    'phone',
    'attempts',
    'locked',
    'gender',
    'birth',
    'joined',
    'updated',
    'active',
    'reset',
    'permission',
    'appress',
    'deleted',
    */
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{view}{ban}',
        'buttons' => array(
            'ban' => array
            (
            'label'=> 'Ban User',
            'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("users/delete", array("id"=>$data->id))' ,

             'click'=>'function(){confirm("Are you sure you want to Ban this ?");}',
            ),
        )
    ),
),
```

));

Comment: I think you should be using [$data, instead of $model](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#value-detail) in that column definition, but that still would not explain the error message you are seeing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
'columns'=>array(
    'id', 
    'name',
    'email',
    array(
        'name' => 'deleted', 
        'value' => '$data->deleted == 1 ? "Yes" : "No"',
     ),
)
```

OR the YII way

```
'columns'=>array(
        'id', 
        'name',
        'email',
        'deleted:boolean'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

At `value` section, You are trying to specify whether `$model->deleted` or not!
if that's the case, then provide a boolean expression before `'?'`

Assuming that deleted returns 1 for true and otherwise for false; EX:

```
'columns'=>array( 'id', 'name', 'email', array( 'name' => 'deleted', 
  'value' => $model- >deleted == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No', ),
```

Comment: I was having a small typo but your solution did not work unfortunately

Comment: It's working now. Can your solution to this issue benefit community? if yes, can you post it? :)

Comment: hmm, Can you post the whole widget? and does deleted mapped to column in that model?